# Recyclerview still freeze/lags while scrolling with DiffUtil on background thread

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, android-diffutils

I have a recyclerview with 20-60 items. I'm using Room+Livedata and Diffutil. The Recyclerview generally updates 2-3 times in a second. Items doesnt change only the items' content modified such as the percentage changes of a currently downloading item. I'm using diffutil in a background thread. I'm dismissing any uptades while diffutil working and only keeping and processing the latest update. I'm not using any ItemAnimator and I pass payloads to change only the percentage on onbindView.

**Shortly**, I have used every possible solution I found to make RecyclerView smoother and faster.

**However**, Scrolling still freezes UI for like 0.2 seconds If an item gets updated while scrolling. It even happens when the item is not visible to the user at that time.

Do you have any suggestions or should I accept this lag and continue?

Comment: show your item.xml and adapter code

Comment: Are you using listadapter?